# SQL change row to other

Tags: sql

I have question about changing row. I would like to swap one row with 3 other rows in which only one column value different
F.e I have Table_1

| Id | Name | HomeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test | 1 |
| 2 | Test2 | 2 |

Table_2

| HomeId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Name1 |
| 2 | Name2 |

in table 2 I delete row wit HomeId = 2 and Insert 3 rows with HomeId = 3,4,5

And I need to update Table_1  Name Test2 with 3 new rows which values of HomeId will be 3,4,5

Comment: you can do the same thing for Table1. delete the row with `HomeId` 2 and insert 3 new rows

Comment: You're missing a cruicial design element which normalises your data, you need a joining table that relates HomeId in table1 to many HomeId in Table 2.

Comment: @Stu Yes, I know about this missing, but generally it's not my missing it's missing of guy who create this many years ago =)

Comment: @SaarLevy but I need to save all values from Table_1 and change only Home_Id

Comment: Is delete and insert in Table_2 are done in same transaction or both are performed separately?

Comment: @Sandeep in one

Comment: Why are you not storing Table_1 homeid = 2 row value temporarily and insert new rows 3,4,5 with values you have in temporary data and delete homeid = 2 in Table_1.  Also It will be helpful if you include code or procedure being used for it

Answer (score -1):

> Can you try this sql query

```js
UPDATE Table_1, Table_2
SET Table_1.HomeId = Table_2.HomeId, Table_1.Name = Table_2.Name
WHERE Table_1.Name = 'Test2'
AND Table_2.HomeId IN (3, 4, 5);
```